# What is the sum of first $n$ terms of the series $1+\frac{1}{4}+3+1+\frac{1}{4}+3+1+\frac{1}{4}+3+\ldots \ldots $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question: What is  the sum of the first $n$ terms of the divergent series :
$$
1+\frac{1}{4}+3+1+\frac{1}{4}+3+1+\frac{1}{4}+3+\ldots \ldots
$$.

My trials: $(1+1+1+\dots)+(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots)+(3+3+3+\dots)$. $n$th term of fist, second, third series are respectively, $a_n=1, b_n=\frac{1}{4}, c_n=3$. What can I do now?

Comment: It will be useful to consider the cases $n=3k, 3k+1,3k+2$ separately.

Comment: Every three terms, $1 + \frac{1}{4} + 3 = \frac{17}{4}$ is added. So for $n \in \{3, 6, 9, 12, \ldots\}$ we have that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $\frac{n}{3} \cdot \frac{17}{4}$. There are two other cases to consider, which should be fairly doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series is divergent

$S_n=\frac {n}{3}\times \frac{17}{4}$, if $n=3k,k\in Z^+$

$S_n=\frac {n+1}{3}\times \frac{17}{4}-3$, if $n=3k-1,k\in Z^+$

$S_n=\frac {n+2}{3}\times \frac{17}{4}-\frac{13}{4}$, if $n=3k-2,k\in Z^+$

Comment: @ LH It is not covering the cases n=1,2

Comment: @ BSC-  I will check now, thanks